# Making ANE for OS X. FREDispatchStatusEventAsync error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, actionscript-3, ane

Im trying to build Air Native Extension for OS X, by using this guide http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt3.html

All seems okay, but I cant send Events to as3, because `FREDispatchStatusEventAsync` function does not works.
When I build my library in Xcode, I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_FREDispatchStatusEventAsync", referenced from:
      _MyANEInitializer in MyANE.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you using AIR 16?

Comment: Sure. Im using latest AIR(16) and Flex(4.6.0) versions.
For building as3 part using Flash Builder 4.6.
For building objective-c part using Xcode 6.1.
And Im working in OS X Yosemite(10.10.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the solution of my problem, but now I can build Objective-C part, and rest parts of ANE.

I set the Architectures and Valid Architectures only to i386. Well, it still not works, but that is another question.